# Is it possible to monitor the scaling operations of Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

We've got an eventhub triggered function that is resulting in excessive duplicate message processing. A second processor is stealing the lease mid process which is resulting in the message being processed, being processed again by the second processor.

Is there any way to monitor these activities, I don't see any trace information that shows that the lease for a partition is being stolen by a different processor.

Is there any way within a function to detect its lease is still valid. If we could we could prevent a downstream action being sent. As it is, that's being sent but when the checkpoint occurs it fails and thus the message is replayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# or F# then you can modify the function to [accept a CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#cancellation-tokens) and that token will be triggered when a lease is lost. This will allow you to reduce (but not completely eliminate) the amount of duplicate processing. Unfortunately there is no equivalent in other languages at this time.

Comment: I tried that and no cancellation is occurring. The lease is taken 1 second before the active function finishes but nothing. 
We just get an exception when the checkpoint tries to be save after the function has finished.

Comment: In the V1 functions the PartitionContext is this a live connection to the blob, i.e. if I look a the owner property will it either show the owner has changed, or error because I don't have a lease on the blob anymore?

Comment: It would also be very nice to have the partition. Lease information output in the telemetry. Just like the host startup information

Comment: Would you mind filing an issue in https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk and tagging me about the cancellation token not being fired. More investigation is required.